# Is there a way to use hyperlink from within draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, confluence

Is there a way to include a hyperlink from the text in one of the draw.io objects? This would help to link from the diagram to relevant Confluence pages.

Answer (score 5):

Select the cell, then from the menu use Edit->Edit Link, insert the URL, click OK.

A new right click menu option will appear "Open link" that then takes you to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, choose the macro 'iFrame' and then paste the link. You should also change the width to 100% and the height as well. I usually use anything up to 1024.